# Python - Log Transformation on variables using numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on feature engineering process as part of a machine learning project. And currently I have to determine whether to do log transformation for certain columns or not.

I came to know that log transformation should be done on those columns which are having skew distribution of values.

Now here are my questions / doubts for which I need clarifications.

**How do I determine in Python whether a particular column values belong to skew distributions(either right skew or left skew) ?**

And assume that I have determined the columns over which I need to apply log transformation, there are many bases to the log function such as loge, log10, log2, etc... **So do I use natural log (i.e) loge or log10 or anything else in this machine learning approach ?**

**And if I am not wrong, log transformation can be applied only on numeric variables. Is this right ?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pandas `DataFrame.skew(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)` [Pandas skew](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.skew.html) to see weather the values of a particular column is skewed or not.

Basically, natural log transormation is preferable and it can be applied only numerical values except zero and negative values.

**The skewness for a normal distribution is zero, and any symmetric data should have a skewness near zero. Negative values for the skewness indicate data that are skewed left and positive values for the skewness indicate data that are skewed right. By skewed left, we mean that the left tail is long relative to the right tail. Similarly, skewed right means that the right tail is long relative to the left tail.**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apply log transformation to numerical data only. There are other alternative ways to convert text data into numerical ex. one-hot-encoding.

Plot the histogram of columns to check if there is any skewness in the data. Box plot also helps in this regards.

If you are using pandas then hist() function will be helpful. Try to plot with different bin sizes.
For log transformation select any base, that won't impact much. Generally loge and log10 are used.

Comment: Thanks @Chitrasen but there is a problem to me. My application will not be having visualization capability. So I have to check whether a particular column has skewness much enough to do log transformation or not without viewing any plots / graphs. Is there something like if hist(col) is 0.7 or some value then we have to do log transformation ?

Comment: @JKC workable alternate is get sample from the data and plot.

Comment: In order to avoid getting errors (if a value is zero) while taking log, I am doing +1 to every cell in the column and taking log of cell value. For example if any cell contains value as '0' then log(0) will end in error. So I am adding 1 to it thereby I am doing log(0+1) which is 0. But if any cell has negative values, how to handle it while taking log. Any pointers to this will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

to measure the skew you can use [`scipy.stats.skew`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skew.html) or [`scipy.stats.skewtest`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.skewtest.html)

You can also use [`scipy.stats.lognorm.fit()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html) to get the parameters for the lognormal distribution

Comment: Thanks @Maarten Fabre When I tried the first option it is throwing error as module 'scipy' has not attribute skew or skewtest

Comment: Oh yes. Its scipy.stats. Ok so when I use skew(col_value) I am getting another value but how to determine its skewness. Is there anything like if the skew() returns a value > 0.5 it's right skew; if its < 0.5 it's left skew ?

Comment: did you read the documentation? `For unimodal continuous distributions, a skewness value > 0 means that there is more weight in the right tail of the distribution`